# Background image is not displaying in full Div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent Div which contains three nested Div's.Now as per my requirement i have to add background image of the parent Div and all other child divisions should come under it but the parent Div background image is displaying in half of the parent Div whereas i want to show in full of parent Div .I am not getting what i am missing.

Here is my HTML..

```
<div id="innerbody" class="inner-body">

 //First Div      

<div id="tele" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:1080px; height:325px;">
<div id="telec" style="position:inherit; float:left; width:180px; height:325px;">
<p style="padding-top:20px;">
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
 Telecommunication</p>
</div>
<div id="teledesc" style="position:inherit; width:870px; margin-top:20px; height:325px; float:left;">
</div>
</div>
</div>

  //Second and Third Div like this

</div>
```

And Here is my css..

```
 .inner-body
{
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto; 
width:100%; 
height:1350px; 
margin-top:-20px; 
font-size:18px; 
color: #6c3f00; 
background: url('../img/new_images/innerbody_bg.jpg') center center no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Please help me ..Thanks

Comment: try background size cover

Comment: to be more precise plunker it are just make a fiddle

Comment: @Benjamin yes it is coming but will it be OK for all Screen Sizes..I mean responsive..

Comment: Yes it will work if u need more info just showcase your code let me take a quick look

Comment: @Benjamin That is my all code..Thanks sir ..

Comment: Hey u need it to showcase in plunker or fiddle which is online showcase for web developer or designers

Answer (score 0):

I think your question isn't clear enough and didn't provide fiddle but did you mean something like this?

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hrkj6b28/)

If yes, add this to the class `.inner-body`:

```
display: table;
width: 100%;
background: url('../img/new_images/innerbody_bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```